# Column 'media_id' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: php, sql

Hi I am trying to get this sql query to work but I keep getting this error, just wondering if someone could point out to me what have I done wrong ?

My sql query

```
SELECT title,blurb,media_id
FROM media_career_crossref 
INNER JOIN media 
ON media.media_id = media_career_crossref.media_id
```

I have got a media table and also a media_career_crossref table. the media_id is in the media table the media_id column in the media_career_crossref ref is linked into this table hence the inner join

Could you explain why it is doing this ? and how I would prevent it from happening again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it with an alias:

```
SELECT title,blurb,m.media_id
FROM media_career_crossref mcc
INNER JOIN media m 
ON m.media_id = mcc.media_id
```

Answer (score 5):

Both tables (media and media_career_crossref) have a column named media_id. In the SELECT statement, you must specify from which table you want to get the value from.  E.g.

```
SELECT title,blurb, media_career_crossref.media_id
FROM media_career_crossref 
INNER JOIN media 
ON media.media_id = media_career_crossref.media_id
```

Comment: the media_id is in the media_id table the one in media_career_crossref is ment to be linked from the other table so would this would work or is it something else.

Comment: @user3266354 I'm not sure I understand your comment. Even if the media_id column from one table is linked to other table by a foreign key, SQL does not assume anything when interpreting your query. For instance, in some complex schemas, you might find some need to reference non-identical values in a query. So whenever you join tables where the same column name appears, always specify which table the column should come from.  In your query, it seems either table is fine, since you are joining on identical media_id values.

Answer (score 1):

Try prefixing the column.
engine must know from what table you want to get it

```
SELECT title,blurb,media.media_id
FROM media_career_crossref 
INNER JOIN media 
ON media.media_id = media_career_crossref.media_id
```